# jQuery SESSION problem with Google Chrome and Safari on MAC OS x 10.5 only

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, safari

I have a problem with the following code, which doesn't want to work in Chrome and Safari:

```
function updateBasket(data) {
if (data != '') {
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(k, data.remove) == -1 && $('.' + k).length > 0) {
            $('.' + k).html(v);
        }
    });
}
}

$('.add_to_basket').live('click', function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var classes = $(this).attr("class");
    var identity = $(this).attr("rel").split('_');
    var url = '/basket/action/add/type/' + identity[0] + '/id/' + identity[1];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url, 
        data: ({ cls : classes }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                updateBasket(data);
                button.replaceWith(data.button);
            }   
        }       
    });
    return false;
});
```

The .add_to_basket trigger only works with the first click - after that it doesn't do anything.
It works fine with Firefox and IEs, but for some reason Chrome and Safari doesn't seem to like it.

Here's the json response which comes after first click:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "items": {
        "27": {
            "price": "120.00",
            "qty": 1,
            "discount": 0,
            "vat": 0,
            "price_vat": 120
        }
    },
    "bundles": [],
    "no_of_items": 1,
    "sub_total": "&pound;120.00",
    "vat_total": "&pound;0.00",
    "total": "&pound;120.00",
    "remove": ["remove", "error", "button", "items", "basket"],
    "button": "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button button_red add_to_basket\" rel=\"item_27\">Remove from the basket<\/a>"
}
```

and the one which comes after second one (returning to the initial state):

```
{
    "error": false,
    "items": [],
    "bundles": [],
    "no_of_items": 0,
    "sub_total": "&pound;0.00",
    "vat_total": "&pound;0.00",
    "total": "&pound;0.00",
    "remove": ["remove", "error", "button", "items", "basket"],
    "button": "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button button_blue add_to_basket\" rel=\"item_27\">Add to the basket<\/a>"
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

To make it even difficult - this is only happening with Chrome and Safari on Mac OSX 10.5 (Leopard) - but doesn't on Snow Leopard - using the same versions of browsers (Chrome 11.0.696.71)

Just an update - I've done a few tests and it appears to be a problem with SESSIONS. It doesn't allow me to log in either - meaning session is not created when using Chrome or Safari on Mac OS X 10.5.

Any idea?

Comment: What url is being sent in each case?  Can you use a debugger to watch what the whole request and response is?

Comment: Same url every time - just parameters in the url might be different. Debug info window is empty.

Comment: This smells of something being sent wrong or a backend issue.  Clearly you are getting a response.  So is the backend doing something wrong?  If you copy/paste the url from a failing case to your url bar, do you get the same thing back?

Comment: I get exactly same json array printed out. I think the problem might be with the 'button' index which sends the html formatted item. Are there any known issues with sending html back as json?

Comment: Sorry - just to clarify - these responses are received when using Firefox not the browsers in question.

Comment: I've just tried chroma by putting url directly to the url field and it looks like it is the html - have a look at the output: {"error":false,"items":{"27":{"price":"120.00","qty":1,"discount":0,"vat":0,"price_vat":120}},"bundles":[],"no_of_items":1,"sub_total":"£120.00","vat_total":"£0.00","total":"£120.00","remove":["remove","error","button","items","basket"],"button":"Remove from the basket<\/a>"}

Comment: hmm - now, even thou I've removed the html - it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is serving your backend?

Comment: The entire application is built in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I've figured out what was causing problems:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}
```

which should simply be:

```
session_start();
```

as it checks on its own whether the session is set.

Thanks for participating everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple testcase at jsfiddle. Im not sure why your example works in other browser, but it shouldn't unless you have omitted some code from the question.

Here is a working example which works in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/ZtTeg/2/

In order to make it work, i had to add parse the returned html button into a jquery element (it seems that only then is the click handler added)

```
    var replacement = $(data.button)
    button.replaceWith(replacement)
```

Tested this with firefox and chrome, and it works here.
Hope this helps.

---

In addition you say you have some problems with the backend (SESSION). I can't help you with that, but when mcoking/emulating the response recieved in my testcase it all seems to work as you wanted. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - it appears however that the problem is really with the sessions - as it doesn't create a session on the server after button is clicked. I've also tried login form - and I can't log in either - really strange - this is the first time I've come across something like this.